# Does Ubuntu Phone APIs include Qt Mobility?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt

I'm currently developping an application for Meego/Harmattan.
This app uses Qt Mobility API, and can easily be ported to SailfishOS. I would like to know if this API is also supported in Ubuntu Phone ?

Comment: If you tell us which particular API of Qt Mobility you are using, we can then point you to the right packages to install to use it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Currently I'm using Qt Location API (namely QGeoPositionInfo andQGeoPositionInfoSource)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu SDK uses Qt5, and in Qt5 the QtMobility library was split into several independent ones, like Qt Location, Qt Organizer, Qt Sensors, etc.  Those will be available on Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: Any chance you could give package names and/or the proper import statements? I'm having a hell of a time figuring this out...

Comment: It seems Qt Location is not quite finished for Qt5. At least it was not at this time: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23659.

Comment: Would anyone know the name of an equivalent of `QtMessaging` [from the Nokia site](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Read_and_send_SMS_messages_using_the_Qt_Messaging_API) -- that lets you access sms?